# I want to display User data from Firebase to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from Firebase to recyclerView through FirebaseRecyclerOptionsbut it keeps showing blanks pages,I want to display the registered Users in my App and there details in a layout,I have no idea where I have gone wrong,I have multi check on my codes and I can't see any error Please can Anyone help me here.
Here Are Code for ListAdapter,Model and ListActivity

```
    public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
        private DatabaseReference reference;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ListAdapter listAdapter;
        private String CurrentUserID;
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.children_home_list);
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            CurrentUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Children Home Details");
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                            .setQuery(reference, Model.class)
                            .build();
            listAdapter = new ListAdapter(options);
    
    
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            listAdapter.startListening();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            listAdapter.stopListening();
        }

public class ListAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
    public ListAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {

        holder.Name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.Phone.setText(model.getPhone());
        holder.Location.setText(model.getLocation());
        holder.Email.setText(model.getMailAddress());
        //Glide.with(holder.circleImageView.getContext()).load(model.IMAGELINK()).into(holder.circleImageView);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,parent,false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }
    class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView circleImageView;
        TextView Name,Phone,Email,Location;
        public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.HomeName);
            Phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneName);
            Email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.paypalAddress);
            Location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        }
    }
}
public class Model {
    String Name,Phone,Location,MailAddress;


    public Model(String name, String phone, String location, String mailAddress) {
        Name = name;
        Phone = phone;
        Location = location;
        MailAddress = mailAddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }

    public String getMailAddress() {
        return MailAddress;
    }

    public void setMailAddress(String mailAddress) {
        MailAddress = mailAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Where did I go wrong here` this doesn't describe your problem at all, please keep in mind that questions here aren't just for you, they're for others in future as well

Comment: have you tried to use a step-by-step debugger?

Comment: Have you tried using a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` rather than a `ListAdapter`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please add the content of your `Model` class.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: I have edited my Question I think its a beat clear